# I have created tree using D3 tree js. Point is I need the value of top and left of each tree node. How can I get the top and left value of tree node?

Tags: jquery, css, d3.js

DOM is:

```
<g id="51" class="node" transform="translate(0,275)">
<circle class="nodeCircle" r="18" style="fill: rgb(98, 98, 191);">
<circle r="18" style="fill-opacity: 0;">

<text class="nodeText" x="0" dy="2em" text-anchor="middle" style="fill-opacity: 1;" y="18">
<tspan dy="14" x="0">Home</tspan>
</text>
<circle class="ghostCircle" r="18" opacity="0.4" style="fill: red;" pointer-events="mouseover">
</g>
```

In JQuery I have tried

```
var pos = element.find('circle.nodeCircle').position();

var rad = element.find('circle.nodeCircle').attr('r');
```

using pos.left and pos.top I am getting the  top and left values of tree node. those values are varying from browser to browser. Any suggestions how can I get the exact top and left values of tree node?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Method 1:

```
var node = element.find('circle.nodeCircle')[0];
var left = node.getBBox().x;    
var top = node.getBBox().y;
```

[Read about getBBox method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff972173(v=vs.85).aspx)

Method 2:

```
var node = element.find('circle.nodeCircle');
var rad = node.attr('r');
var data = d3.select(node[0]).data();
var left  = data.x-rad;
var top  = data.y-rad;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried this code , I am getting same top for each tree node. Any another solution please.

Comment: @Nirmala It's not that you're getting the same top for each node, it's that `d3.select` (as opposed to `selectAll`) only selects the first matching element. And furthermore, the `node()` method only returns the first node in a selection, even if there are multiple nodes in it. You need to loop over all the nodes and build an array of whatever coordinates you need. Use something like `d3.selectAll(".nodeCircle").each(function(d,i) { someArray.push(this.getBBox()); })`

Comment: @meetamit I have tried this , Now I am getting different error: ' ns_error_not_implemented  getBBox() '. Can you please give the library details in which getbbox() is implemented? I have used d3.v3.min.js.

Comment: `getBBox()` is not part of a library, it's a native [method of SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox).  Inside the `.each()` function, the `this` keyword points to the SVG dom element of each circle. Don't know what it doesn't work for you. The only explanation that comes to mind is that you're calling this stuff before appending the nodes, it which case it wouldn't work. You'll have to make a jsFiddle if for anyone to be able to help you.